# Mapbox Reset Zoom when Marker deselected

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

Fairly new to Mapbox and getting there (slowly).

I have a map initially loaded at zoom level 1 for use in a web browser. When a user clicks on a marker, it'll center and zoom to level 10.

When that marker loses focus, I'd like to zoom back out to level 1.

This page discussing web applications does it (link below), but there doesn't seem to be (that I can find - sorry!) any documentation on how to achieve this.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/web-apps/

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For the first event, to zoom in when clicking a marker, you could adapt this example to zoom in addition to panning when calling flyTo

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/center-on-feature/

For the second part, you'd need to add a listener for another event depending on what you have in mind by "losing focus".

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map-events